# How can I write problem type in such a way that the code uses values in a list given and returns them as output after optimisation,not random floats

Tags: optimization, modeling, platypus

[Values to pick from are in list named diameters, and run a simulation. Please see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn3vu.png)

[After optimization using platypus, the results were floats in the range 0.225 to 0.9. Instead of the specific values in diameters list. Please see attached image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYagc.png)